# LazyInitialization Exception stack trace getting printed even if it is handled in a catch block

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a code that gives me a LazyInitialization Exception. I have handled it on demand i.e. the catch block gets executed only if the exception is thrown and the necessary action is taken. But even though I have handled the exception the stack trace for the exception is getting printed as soon as the control enters the catch block, on the console which is not expected. (Since any java exception if handled is not printed in the log file.) Below is my try catch block:

```
try{
     if (tempUser != null) {
    List<FieldAreas> fieldAreasList = tempUser.getFieldAreasList();
    for (FieldAreas fieldArea : fieldAreasList) {
           fieldArea.getId();
           break;
    }
     }
    } catch(LazyInitializationException exception) {
    //This catch block is written to handle lazy initialization exception
    fetchDetailsForMerchant(merchant,defaultPricingInput);
    tempUser = User.findByPrimaryKey(tempUser.getId());
    List<FieldAreas> fieldAreasList = tempUser.getFieldAreasList();
    for (FieldAreas fieldArea : fieldAreasList) {
        fieldArea.getId();
        break;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Check whether `LazyInitializationException` is thrown out from `catch` block itself.

Comment: The exception is being logged as soon as it is caused i.e. just after the for loop's first iteration is executed. Really don't know why is it getting logged even before going to the catch block. I tried to throw other exceptions too but they were handled gracefully n nothing was logged. I doubt if there is something related to LazyInitializationException itself?